# How many polynomials in $Z_{p}[x]$ have degree n or less?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, polynomials, ring-theory

For your reference, $Z_{p}[x]$ refers to the set of all polynomials with coefficients integer mod p.  To me it seems like this and the degree (power) of the two polynomials are unrelated.  What theorem would you use to figure this out?

Comment: When do you consider two polynomials to be equivalent? If their graphs are the same?

Comment: @par graphs?  what would this have to do with the question?

Comment: He means do you distinguish two polynomials who have the same associated polynomial function, like $X$ and $X^{p}$.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is very simple: a polynomial $P$ of degree less than $n$ can be identified to the set of its coefficients $(a_{0},a_{1},...a_{n})$ (with eventually $a_{n}=0$ if $P$ has degree less than $n$).

You have $p$ possibilities for each $a_{i}$ and  you must make this choice $n+1$ times, so the answer is $p^{n+1}$

Comment: +1 Unless of course they are thinking about the nontrivial characterization ^-^

Comment: Yes ! In that case the answer is $p^{\min(n,p)+1}$.